# How would I make this details box for an android app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I was thinking of a button and then just setting the visibility of a box below to true when it's clicked but it doesn't look quite right and I don't know how easily the text on that button can be changed.

[image: What I'm looking for, before/after]

Comment: why dont you use an expandable listview for this

Comment: After looking more at the expandable list view it seems like it does what I want but I'd only have 1 parent group and from the examples I've looked at it's a lot of work for just that. As for what I've tried, I did a button that would make text appear when it was clicked but it didn't turn out too nice. I may try that scroll view CzarMatt mentioned and see how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

First create your horoscope button layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/small_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="You're a Virgo!" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/small_layout"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/detailed_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Put your expanded widgets here-->
            <!-- such as TextView, ImageView, etc-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that the height of the `ScrollView` is initially zero.

Secondly, in your Java code, get a handle on your `ScrollView` and programmatically adjust its layout parameters (height) with a `ValueAnimator` or other animation object when your `ImageButton` arrow is clicked.

Comment: Do you happen to have any resource that may show me how this would look when fully implemented?

Comment: I don't, but I can tell you that when you animate the scrollview's height programmatically, it will look like you are pulling down a shade or pulling out a drawer with the content nested inside.  At the same time, you can animate the arrow icon rotating 90 degrees to the right.  Reverse the animations to hide everything.  I think this would make for a decent looking effect.